# Nginx rewrite and (later) load balancer together: is that possible?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, proxypass

I've an old site based on IIS that, for historical reasons, was using lots of RewriteRule via Helicon APE. Now, when we hit the server with multiple clients, Helicon APE frequently crashes (quite frequently, actually). The entire set of IIS servers (4) are expected to grow and the entire system to scale, and a lot of effort was done recently in the webapp to support new features and user growth.

Someone suggested to use NGINX as a load balancer before the IIS servers, as it will handle way better the increasing amount of traffic, and apply those rewrites before hitting IIS, so the URLs would be converted to the new formats before load balancing them.

Following the advice, we have set one POC nginx 1.13 on linux with rewrite rules (from the ones used in APE) and using proxy_pass with two of the servers. But we have noticed several issues this way:

- rewrite rules seems to NOT work the way they should; we can check that the regex's are certainly valid (putting them in locations), but the URL seems to be not rewritten.
- ProxyPass returns usually a 400 bad request or does not hit the servers.
- However, if we set several locations with some of the simpler regexs, and then we put inside ProxyPass to the backend server and the new URL patterns, the servers are hit with the right requests. This solution, however, brings some problems: some of our rewrites are additions to anothers, so the transformations could be done in 3 steps (one changes first part of the rule, the second changes another, and the third will join all together to put the valid url with a break flag). This is impossible to be done mixing locations.

  A lot of research through StackOverflow, blogs, support sites and mailings lists has been put in place to find a solution to our problem, but sometimes the suggested solution does not work at all (or partially), and to be honest, after a week with this, we are concerned the arquitecture we had in mind is not possible to be done.

  We have tried this with haproxy as well, with really odd behavior from haproxy (ie: sending error messages attached to the request being LB'd).

  As the title summarizes, after the long description above, the question is: can someone confirms what we are trying to achieve can really be done with nginx? If not, what could be used?

Comment: Do you have examples of the rewrite rules that are not working as they should? Is the 400s from nginx or from the IIS servers?

Comment: Actually @ShawnC, found the issue was a misunderstanding of how the rewrites and location work alltogether. After a change on the paradigm to do some tests, and enabled debugging, we were able of start making proper rewrites working in another day.